# Return the first line of a String in Haskell

Tags: html, haskell

I have a fairly simple question that I am stumped on. Basically, I just have to write a function that takes a string, breaks it into lines, takes the first line and returns the first line in properly formatted HTML title tag.

I honestly just don't know where to start with this.

Anything will help.

I do have code, but this is just some of the basic functions that I am using to do the transformations on the input file:

```
    convertToHTML :: String -> String
    convertToHTML cs0 = 
          case cs0 of
                ('#' : '#' : cs) -> "<h2>" ++ cs ++ "</h2>"
                ('#' : cs)       -> "<h1>" ++ cs ++ "</h1>"
                 "---"            -> "<hr/>"
                  _                -> cs0

    convertToHTML' :: String -> String
    convertToHTML' = unlines.map (convertToHTML.firstLine.escapeChars).lines

    convertToWords :: String -> String
    convertToWords cs1 =
                case cs1 of
                      ('*' : '*' : cs) -> "<strong>" ++ cs ++ "</strong>"
                      ('_' : '_' : cs) -> "<strong>" ++ cs ++ "</strong>"
                      ('*' : cs)       -> "<em>" ++ init cs ++ "</em>"
                      ('_' : cs)       -> "<em>" ++ init cs ++ "</em>"
                      _                -> cs1

    convertToWords' :: String -> String
    convertToWords' = unwords.map convertToWords.words
```

these are the basic functions that I am calling from my main, which reads the input file, calls the functions and produces an output file.

```
    main = do
          args <- getArgs -- command line args
          let (infile,outfile) = (\(x:y:ys)->(x,y)) args
          putStrLn $ "Input file:  " ++ infile
          putStrLn $ "Output file: " ++ outfile
          contents <- readFile infile      
          writeFile outfile $ deleteSymbol $ convertToWords' $ convertToHTML' $ contents
```

hopefully you get the gist of the code.

Comment: `titleLine = ("<title>" ++) . (++ "</title>") . head . lines`

Comment: Start at the beginning. I would start with the function that converts to a line to use the HTML title tag.

Comment: @Aadit M Shah when I call this function from my main it prints every line in the tab of the browser. I can't think of why it does that

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the first line you can simply use:

```
firstLine :: String -> String
firstLine = head . lines
```

then you can use:

```
firstLineInTitleTags :: String -> String
firstLineInTitleTags s = concat ["<title>", firstLine s, "</title>"]
```

or:

```
firstLineInTitleTags :: String -> String
firstLineInTitleTags = ("<title>"++) . (++"</title>") . firstLine
```

Comment: okay, lets say I use your first code. So it breaks a String into a List of Strings, in this case Lines, and it gets the head. but in the second code, how do I implement this? I need the first line of my input file to to print into the tab of the browser, which the title tags do. is there any other functions I can $ or . to the first function to achieve this?

Comment: thank you for the edit @Jefffrey. I tried this code as well, and it still prints everything of the input file into the tab of the browser. Not sure how to fix this problem

Comment: @Amateur_Haskell Could you be more specific? I modified the code a little bit and I got the correct result. I also use a function that just applies `firstLineInTitleTags` to the head of the given list and leaves the tail unchanged. If you put a call to a function like that in `convertToHTML'`, it should work.

Comment: @David Young I cant figure that part out. Sure I can add to my convertToHTML', but how do I just get the head? Doesnt firstLine already take care of that? I call from my convertToHTML' by saying   unlines.map (convertToHTML.escapeChars.firstLine').lines

Comment: right there ^ doesnt that break the string into Lines, and map those 3 functions onto those lines? so firstLine' would be called, (my version of firstLineInTitleTags) which would then call firstLine, which breaks the Lines into more lines? takes the head, and prints that in the tags. It just seems like a lot is going on. I know the solution should be simple, but I get an error when I call the function like this.

Comment: @DavidYoung with the code, I'm getting an error saying Prelude.Head empty list. And so, doesnt print anything. I really don't know the problem. Thanks for your help though!